# Laplace-deRham operator for 1-forms on the sphere

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

What do the eigenforms of the 1-form Laplace-de Rham operator look like on the 2-sphere, seen as vector fields via the inner product?

For the standard Laplace-de Rham operator on 0-forms (functions) the simple answer is the spherical harmonics.  What about for the 1-form operator?

Comment: This is probably overkill, but you can take a look at
Folland, "Harmonic analysis of the de Rham complex on the sphere. "
Crelles 1989

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $f:S^2\to R$ satisfies $\Delta f=\lambda f$, then 
$$\Delta(df)=(dd^*+d^*d)(df)=\lambda df$$
and similarly

$$ \Delta(\ast df)=(dd^*+d^*d)(*df)=\lambda \ast df $$

Since $H^1(S^2)=0$, these are all eigenvectors on 1-forms.  Here $*$ is the Hodge * operator and $d^*=-\ast d \ast$.

The vector field is the unique $X$ so that $df(v)=(X,v)$.

On 2-forms all eigenvectors are of the form $\ast f$.